# Is there a certain comedian this South Park episode is referencing?

Tags: reference, south-park

In episode season 20, "Douche and a Danish", Mr. Garrison talks in a manner similar to stand up comedy instead of holding a speech.

[image]

Is this a reference to a certain comedian or just a generic reference?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The cigarette he waves around, the crass misogynistic humor and intentionally insulting his audience until they leave the theater is all [**Andrew Dice Clay**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Dice_Clay) (only instead of the greaser look and NY accent, it's Mr. Garrison's voice in Trump's suit). That was pretty much Clay's schtick until his career faded somewhere around the mid-late 90s. That style is evident in his album [The Day the Laughter Died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Laughter_Died).

> The album is largely improvisational, with Clay interacting with the audience over the course of over an hour and a half. The topics run through his usual gamut of sex, relationships between men and women, masculinity, religion and popular culture. Unlike his prior recordings, **the jokes are delivered intentionally flat and raw as to offend and alienate the audience, turning the performance into the joke itself. Clay's performance results in several members of the audience leaving the show early, some insulting him as they leave.**

[IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/10/20/south-park-douche-and-a-danish-review) and the [AV Club](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/south-park-mixes-todays-trump-outdated-conspiracy--244499) concur that it's Clay-like. Here's some of Clay's act **(Warning: Profane)**:

Comment: To further corroborate, the part of the routine where Garrison talks about waiting in line and sticking his finger up some chick's a-- is a direct reference to Clay's line about waiting in line with his tongue up some chick's a--.

Answer (score 1):

The part where Mr. Garrison says:

> So you've been ok with fuck everyone to death, all the muslims and
>   mexican shit but fingers in the ass did it for ya? Just wanted to see
>   where your line was.

is very reminiscent of [a bit from Jim Jefferies' Alcoholocaust](http://www.ebaumsworld.com/videos/jim-jefferies-people-who-believe-in-god-are-idiots/82525598/) (starts at 06:25), where he says:

> Now, when I started this show my first routine was about how lesbians
>   were fat, ugly, useless, with no sense of humour, and you couldn’t
>   applaud more. Then I killed an Arab man from a f—ing helicopter. Just
>   shot him dead. Then I said… that Christians are bullshit and there is
>   no god. And that’s the moment that half the audience chose to be
>   offended. Was that the f—ing moment that got you?

Comment: The Day The Laughter Died was one of the greatest performance pieces ever staged, long before Shia LeBouf and Jaoquin Phoenix pretended to go off the rails.  It's almost painful to listen to, in so much as you feel horrible for Clay if you didn't know that his whole objective was to see how far he had to go to completely alienate himself from the audience.